# MySQL Changing storage engine table

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with a version of MySQL installed manually. I have also installed an engine storage of third party.

My problem is this.

When I change the engine of a table in my database to the third party engine installed I don't see the table engine changing.

For clarify when I execute the command

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'XXX'
```

I can see that the table engine is InnoDB.

If I execute the command

```
ALTER TABLE XXX ENGINE = <third party engine>
```

and again I execute the command

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'XXX'
```

the table engine is not changed to the third party engine storage.

I am working on an Ubuntu server in Amazon.
Version of MySQL installed manually: 5.5.37

Why I have this behavior? A problem with the installed third party engine storage?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: After the `ALTER TABLE` statement, try tge query `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: Hi Michael. I have already use SHOW WARNINGS but without results.

Comment: @Lorenzo `A problem with the installed third party engine storage?` Do you think we can tell without any information about it?

Comment: Hi @fancyPants. This post is very old and actually I have changed my MySQL installation. The Third party engine storage is MyDiamo (unknown to most). However, my question was if the problem that I'd had was on MySQL or on this Third party engine storage.

Comment: Well, google for bug reports describing your observed behaviour. If there are none (which is what I assume), it pretty sure is a problem of your third party engine.